# file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/log.htm) is not within the allowed path(s):

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am generating PDF file using DOMPDF in CodeIgniter, it works fine in localhost. But it gives me the following error after uploading the files to the server.

```
Message: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/log.htm) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/fryapps.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp)

Filename: src/Dompdf.php

Line Number: 714
```

This is my code

```
$htmlcontent= $this->load->view('admin/test',$data,true);           
$this->pdf->loadHtml($htmlcontent);
$this->pdf->render();           
$this->pdf->stream("report.pdf",array("Attachment=>0"));
```

I have followed many answers from google but I couldn't fix my problem. please how can i resolve this??

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the file, to line 714 and changing tmp to home/admin/tmp

Comment: I can't find (/tmp/log.htm)  in the file.

Comment: could you send the file or a link to it?

Comment: you want to see the DOMpdf file?it works fine in local but not in server.